# macro to print a string

Tags: c++, string, macros

How the PLUS macro work if i pass two strings to it, and it will parse them as the enum value?
Thanks in advance.
Sorry that i can't express myself too clearly.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT(Y) #Y
#define PLUS(X, Y) X+Y

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    typedef enum {
        FIRST,
        SECOND,
        THIRD
    };

    const char *a="THIRD", *b="SECOND";
    cout << PRINT(THIRD+SECOND is: ) << PLUS(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). And **never** make a non-const `char *` point to a string literal.

Comment: And why do you need a macro here?  Why isn't `std::cout << a` enough?

Comment: @JoeZ are you really complaining that he posted a short test example explaining only his problem, and not the entire code he's working on? C'mon.

Comment: I think there's some confusion what the objective is.

Comment: @Staven:  No, I'm asking what "printout the content of `char *a`" means that's different from "`cout << a`".  `cout << a` prints the string pointed to by `a`, and it's already in his test.

Comment: I can't understand the question, are you saying that you can't compile it because of a dependency, or are you asking how it works?

Comment: thank you chris, i added const and "str" is replaced

Comment: jor Joe Z, that's a scenario i used, i need to pass a string to a macro, and the macro use the string plaintext as an ENUM value.

Comment: qrikki, i am asking how it works.

Comment: If what you want is the 2dn and 3rd couts to print the content of a, just remove the # from _TMP macro. If not, I really dont understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @miniduan: Usually folks are trying to do the opposite:  `stringify( enum_value )` so that the non-string `enum_value` becomes a quoted string.

Answer (score 2):

I think, from your followup comment, that I understand better what you're trying to do:  Trying to make both a string form and non-string form of a symbol such as an enum value.

The way I usually do this is as follows:

```
#define Q(x) QQ(x)
#define QQ(x) #x
```

Then you use it with a *non-string* value, such as an enum:

```
enum { FRED = 1, BARNEY = 2 };

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The enum " << Q( FRED   ) << " has the value " << FRED   << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The enum " << Q( BARNEY ) << " has the value " << BARNEY << std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

```
The enum FRED has the value 1
The enum BARNEY has the value 2
```

If that's not what you're trying to accomplish, please clarify in your question and leave me a comment.

Comment: Hi Joe, i edited my question and made it a bit clearer.

Comment: @miniduan:  After seeing your revised question, I believe what you ask for is not possible.  The compiler needs to see `enum` values as identifiers at _compile_ time. There is no way to "unstring" and get to an enum identifier hidden in a string literal.  The compiler can go in the opposite direction, and put quotes around something (ie.  turn `FIRST` into `"FIRST"`).  If you need to look up strings and turn them into values, you can do that at _run_ time (not _compile_ time), using something like `std::map<string, int>`.

Comment: In the context of your example, you could have written `cout << "THIRD + SECOND is " << THIRD + SECOND << endl` with no macros.  What is also unclear is why you need that additional level of indirection.

Comment: Hi @Joe Z, thanks so much for your following up. The reason i do that is: i am in a scenario of JNI. the JNI passes a string value of the ENUM name. and my macro using the ENUM value to calculate. Currently my solution is to compare  the enum names: if (str="FIRST", then use FIRST enum to logic)

Comment: @miniduan:  Ok, then what you'll need to do is look up the values in some other structure, such as `map<string, int>`.  The detail about JNI, and the fact that the strings are coming from outside the C++ environment is actually rather important, because you have to resolve the name at run time, not compile time.

Comment: yes, map the string to its int value is a good idea. Because the external string could not really be resolved by C++. Thanks a lot!